# Checking for an uppercase in strings inside a list

Tags: string, python-2.7, list, uppercase, lowercase

I have been tasked to do a small mission
for a list that contains only strings I need to check the following and create a list if there is a capital letter in the string I need to isolate that word and put it in the new list as a separate word,
for example for the list

str_list = [“This”, “is”, “not a Red”, “”, “wine, but a white One”]

the new one needs to look like this

split_str_list = [“This”, “is”, “not a ”, ”Red”, “”, “wine, but a white “, ”One”]

thank you very much for the help

Comment: Please share the code you tried and post what issue you are facing exactly and the error message. Happy to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_list = ["This","is","not a Red","","Wine, but a white One"]
new_list=[]
string=''
for i in str_list:
    print i
    words=i.split(' ')
    print words
    for x in words:
        if x == ' ' or x=='':
            new_list.append(x)

        elif x[0].isupper() and string != '':
            string=string.strip()
            new_list.append(string)
            new_list.append(x)
            string=''
        elif x[0].isupper() and string == '':
            new_list.append(x)

        else:
            string=string+x+' '
print new_list
```

> OUTPUT:['This', 'is not a', 'Red', '', 'Wine,', 'but a white', 'One']